# Laravel Keeps rounding Numbers

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project that for some reasons keeps on rounding numbers when saving them into the database.

Here is my model:

```
/**
 * Adds a pur order.
 *
 * @param      <array>   $data   The data
 *
 * @return     boolean , int id purchase order
 */
public function add_pur_order($data){

    $data['order_date'] = to_sql_date($data['order_date']);

    $data['delivery_date'] = to_sql_date($data['delivery_date']);

    $data['datecreated'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $data['addedfrom'] = get_staff_user_id();

    if(isset($data['pur_order_detail'])){
        $pur_order_detail = explode (',', $data['pur_order_detail']);
        unset($data['pur_order_detail']);
        $es_detail = [];
        $row = [];
        $rq_val = [];
        $header = [];
        $header[] = 'item_code';
        $header[] = 'unit_id';
        $header[] = 'unit_price';
        $header[] = 'quantity';
        $header[] = 'into_money';
        $header[] = 'tax';
        $header[] = 'total';
        $header[] = 'discount_%';
        $header[] = 'discount_money';
        $header[] = 'total_money';

        for ($i=0; $i < count($pur_order_detail); $i++) {
            
                $row[] = $pur_order_detail[$i];
            
            if((($i+1)%10) == 0){
                $rq_val[] = array_combine($header, $row);
                $row = [];
            }
        }
        foreach($rq_val as $key => $rq){
            if($rq['item_code'] != ''){
                array_push($es_detail, $rq_val[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(isset($data['dc_total'])){
        $data['discount_total'] = reformat_currency_pur($data['dc_total']);
        unset($data['dc_total']);
    }

    if(isset($data['dc_percent'])){
        $data['discount_percent'] = $data['dc_percent'];
        unset($data['dc_percent']);
    }

    $this->db->insert(db_prefix() . 'pur_orders', $data);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    if ($insert_id) {
        // Update next estimate number in settings
        $total = [];
        $total['total'] = 0;
        $total['total_tax'] = 0;
        $total['subtotal'] = 0;
       
        foreach($es_detail as $key => $rqd){
            $es_detail[$key]['pur_order'] = $insert_id;
            $total['total'] += $rqd['total_money'];
            $total['total_tax'] += ($rqd['total']-$rqd['into_money']);
            $total['subtotal'] += $rqd['into_money'];
        }

        if($data['discount_total'] > 0){
            $total['total'] = $total['total'] - $data['discount_total'];
        }

        $this->db->insert_batch(db_prefix().'pur_order_detail',$es_detail);

        $this->db->where('id',$insert_id);
        $this->db->update(db_prefix().'pur_orders',$total);

        return $insert_id;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The problem I have is specifically related to **quantity**. If I am to enter 20.10 (just and example, but applies to any decimal number) I still end up having a saved value in the database of 20.

Furthermore I have also seen to change the table for quantity (which was previously set to varchar) to DECIMAL, however with the same result.

What is the best way to have this fixed? This should only apply for quantity. Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Are these numbers being actually rounded or truncated (decimal values are removed)? ie. if you try to store the number 20.90, do you get 21 or do you get 20?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. I am getting 21

Comment: I am unfortunately not sure, I don't see anything in your code suggesting that rounding would happen - the quantity value does not seem to be manipulated at all. Perhaps try placing dd(); statements at different points in your code to try and determine which line is responsible for the rounding.

Comment: Have you tried inserting directly into the database, using some SQL client instead of your code, just to make sure that it's not the database doing it?

Comment: What kind of `DECIMAL` did you define it in the database structure? Did you define it like `DECIMAL(5,0)`?

Comment: @aceraven777 Hi there and thanks for your answer, I've defined it as (15,0)

Comment: @GregSchmidt I've just tested this, and if I am to edit the value in quantity through phpmyadmin I get: Data truncated for column 'quantity' at row 1

Comment: Was able to get this fixed by changing the quantity table to varchar(255)

Comment: Why do you have to change it to `varchar(255)`? For numeric purposes it s better to use `DECIMAL(15,2)` if you want it in 2 decimal places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `DECIMAL(X,Y)`. `X` being the total length and `Y` being the number of decimals you would like to keep.

Using string might give you more problems in the future when you're trying to ensure integrity of the data type.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp